# Self Review: Should I mention the times I was 'disappointed with myself'

Tags: performance-reviews

I have joined a big company as an intern around three months back and I am still in College (so this is my first job) and I have been asked to write a self performance review.

On a general note, I am happy with what I have done. I have delivered an excellent JavaScript module, as a standout.

However, there was one time where I was a bit negligent* in a task and that led to a delay in the completion of that task and sprint goals were not met because of me. I was quite disappointed with myself at that time.

After a week, similar but different task came again. I took the task again (hoping to amend my mistakes) and was able to perform well.

So, my question is, **should I mention "that" time when I was negligent**? If yes, how should I phrase it so that it comes out that I actually learned from it?

Thanks

*I didn't know how that thing worked, and therefore went badly "out of schedule".

Comment: I want to point out that we generally encourage you not to accept an answer too quickly. You may want to give other people a chance to submit an answer as well and accepting early tends to discourage other people from replying. You are free to change or remove the mark-as-answered tick at any time and you may want to do so and wait [one or two days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/260382) before evaluating the answers you received and accepting the one that you found the most helpful.

Comment: What country are you in? The answer here may vary somewhat based on that.

Comment: @Lilienthal, point noted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, my question is, should I mention "that" time when I was negligent?
>   If yes, how should I phrase it so that it comes out that I actually
>   learned from it?

Yes!

One of the key aspects of a good internship is learning. Demonstrating self-awareness in this area is a good thing, and it might get you some valuable feedback on how to improve.

Just point out the activity that occurred to make you feel disappointed. Don't use the term "negligent", as it has connotations that probably aren't appropriate in this context.

Talk about what you would have done differently if you had a chance to do it over.

Then, listen for a response.

When I hired interns, I viewed it as a learning opportunity first, an audition for a potential future job second, and as a way to earn a check last. I felt that it was my job to give them honest, productive feedback on their performance. I believe that helpful feedback is one of the most valuable things a young worker can get.

You might go into an internship not knowing the field, and not even knowing how to work effectively. The fact that you are now showing awareness and looking for such feedback would be viewed extremely favorably, if you worked for me.

Comment: @akshay Also, don't use the term disappointed. It is counterproductive to judge yourself - I assume you are willing to learn from the past (otherwise you would not have asked here), which is what counts.

Comment: @JanDoggen, yes I am willing to learn. And how about if I phrase it like, "I prevented my team to meet their sprint goals and this was a big disappointment." ? Here the *situation* is the disappointment.

Comment: Early in my career I was told by a wise senior engineer, NEVER point out your flaws in reviews. Very few other people are going to point out their flaws. All you do by pointing out your flaws is give a reason to lower your ranking. Usually what you point out is something that likely would have been forgotten or gone unnoticed if you didn't bring it up. There should be plenty of positive accomplishments to amply fill up allotted space that you don't need to delve into the negatives. If there isn't then it probably doesn't matter what you write, because others will already have a low opinion.